# iPad stretched my content to fit the screen when I don't want it to

Tags: css, ipad, safari, viewport

Ok, so I have set up my site, it looks great in mobile, tablet landscape, desktop etc etc, BUT on iPad, in portrait mode, it is stretching the content to fill the screen. the content is all set to 420px wide using skeleton.css. I have the viewport settings set up like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, , user-scalable=no" />
```

But still, in portrait mode the content is all appearing at full width, at 768px instead of the 420px I have set it to...

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your input!

**UPDATE:**
I have worked around it by decreasing the media query width so that now the portrait tablet receives the same view as the landscape tablet. It's not what I wanted, but it works ok.

It looks to me like the iPad stretches the width of content if it is small than the device, but if the content is bigger it just displays it at the dimensions you specify in the css... If anyone knows any more about this, please post, as I would be interested in knowing for other projects.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the extra comma in your meta tag causing your issue? Maybe try `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />`

Answer (score 0):

You could override the CSS that is getting changed on the iPad using media queries. This will allow you to target the iPad specifically and will give you more control over how the page is displayed on that device (this can also potentially cause issues with your CSS elsewhere).

You can do this in your CSS:

```
/* iPad Portrait */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* CSS overrides for iPad go here */
}
```

Or in your HTML (overrides in a separate CSS file):

```
<link rel="stylesh`eet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="../iPadStyles.css" type="text/css" />
```

There are also media queries for retina displays [here](http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/03/css-for-iphone-ipad-and-retina-displays/). If you're not familiar with media queries, I'd recommend checking on the documentation on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Thanks, but I already have media queries in place targeting the iPad landscape and portrait. I have set them up only using max-width/ min-width rather than device-width and I haven't included the orientation, but they work for iPad landscape and mobile which make me think its not to do with the media queries. It feels like the iPad is scaling my site... I will try including orientation and see if it makes any difference.